# Parse JSON with JQuery - parseJSON/getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON file that has this code:

```
{
    "employees": [
        { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
        { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
        { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
    ]
}
```

with this small script:

```
<script>
    var obj = $.parseJSON("employe.json")
</script>
```

I just want to use the employees object, but I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character @ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
```

I also tried the same thing with `getJSON`, but it did not work either.

Is `getJSON` for external files and `parseJSON` for json string?

Comment: `parseJSON` parses json strings into objects. `getJSON` uses `parseJSON` internally, so it does the parsing automagically. When you get the "unexpected character" error, it's almost always because the JSON is invalid, and there are characters that should'nt be there.

Comment: I copied and pasted my JSON file, do you see any error?

Comment: You can test your json at : http://jsonlint.com/, also the error console should tell you what character is causing the problem.

Comment: You should *always* read the documentation. I guess if you had looked at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/, you would have seen that it accepts a *JSON string*, not a URL. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ also provides some examples, maybe they are helpful?

Comment: Read what I said, I was already assuming parseJSON was taking a string. The reason I was using parseJSON, was becuse getJSON wasn't working. But thanks for the help!

Comment: I read the question. But you wouldn't have to mention it if you already knew that it was the wrong method. It is just unnecessary information in this case which distracts from the real problem. You said *"getJSON wasn't working"*. What exactly did not work? Was the request not sent? Was the response not received? Was the response in the wrong format? Even the HTTP status code can already be helpful. Use your browser's developer tools (I recommend Chrome) to find this out. Post your `$.getJSON` code.

Comment: Also add an error callback (with `$.getJSON(...).fail(function(error) {...})`) and find out if there is an error and which one it is.

Comment: This is my script: 
var hey = $.getJSON("employe.json"); And my only error is that it says my JSON is malformed, while the JSON validator says it's valid. I will try the error callback.

Comment: What do you expect the variable `hey` to be here? It won't be the data you are trying to load, it will be an jqXHR object. Ajax functions are all asynchronous, you have to use a callback. The documentation has examples how to call the method.

Comment: The variable hey was because I saw this example on W3S: var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")"); I thought it worked the same way with the getJSON JQuery function. So I removed the variable hey and getJSON only take one obligatory argument, so I don,t see why $.getJSON("employe.json"); is still not working and giving me the malformed error even though my JSON is all valid.

Comment: Oh I see now, I need to use the sucess callback to parse the JSON.

Comment: `getJSON` will parse the response automatically for you.

Comment: This seems to be a good syntax: $.getJSON("employe.json", function(data) {
  document.write(data.employees[0].firstName);
  });, because I don't get an error for that, but I still get a malformed error in Firebug that point to the fist { of my JSON file. It's suppose to be valid, because I validated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be loading the json file first, then sending the resulting string contents of that document into the parse statement.

```
$.ajax({url: "employe.json"}).done(function(data){
    console.log($.parseJSON(data));
});
```

Comment: I see, I need to load the JSON file first. I still get a similar error: "malformed". And it points to the first bracket of my JSON file.

Comment: Oh right. But I just found out that getJSON is a shortcut to that.

Comment: Just did and all my JSON is valid :S

Comment: Log out data before you parse it, make sure it's loading the data. Maybe also try using JSON.parse instead (remove a layer.)

Comment: @Maxwell did you get this sorted?